# Ubuntu 12.04 ASUS USB-N13 802.11 b/g/n wireless connection weak after reboot

Tags: wireless

I have struggled with slow wireless connection for months. To find a solution, I have searched and read many posts about slow/intermittent wireless connections, and tried the suggestions with partial success. Now I have got it working but every time I reboot my system, the wireless speed goes down significantly. I can test this by the command `iwconfig`. So after each reboot I have to remove the driver and install it again to get my wireless speed back. Here is some more info:

OS:  Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
USB:  ASUS USB-N13 802.11 b/g/n
USB driver:    Realtek RTL8192CU version 4.0.2_9000
Command to remove the driver:    `sudo rmmod rtl8192cu`
Command to install:    sudo bash ./install.sh (to be run from the driver's directory)

By the way, this does not happen when I suspend the system, only when I reboot. I was wondering if anybody can tell me why this is happening. What process gets in the way of wireless that after reboot it becomes so slow?!

Comment: Are you using a driver parameter that is not permanently set?

Comment: I am not sure how to check for that. I ran the iwconfig before and after reboot. Here are some of the listed values: (Good connection: Bit Rate = 144.4 Mb/s, Retry=off, RTS thr=off, Power Management=off, Link quality=100/100), (weak connection: Bit Rate = 72.2 Mb/s, Retry long limit=7, RTS thr=2347 B, Power Management=off, Link Quality=60/70)

Answer (score 0):

If your slowdown is heavily linked with reboots, you might want to see if there's a startup application that is hampering your wireless card. See if there's anything suspicious in "Startup Applications". (open from Dash)

Or instead, run another OS on your computer and see if the same problem occurs. If not, then we'd know the issue is Ubuntu-specific, which would narrow down our scope of possible error sources.

Also have your computer scanned. Just to be on the safe side.

If none of these work, install an earlier, more stable version of your wireless driver. My USB 3.0 driver, for instance, doesn't work with the latest version. Manufacturers make mistakes every once in a while.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I have a dual-boot system, and Windows wireless speed is quite good. I looked at my Startup Application Preferences; the only item listed is "NVIDIA X Server Settings". How can I scan the Ubuntu partition of my computer?